# Picker not working properly on iOS

Tags: codenameone

Could you guys take a look at this Video?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47281022/Reflector%20Recording.mp4

As you can see, the picker stopped working properly for some reason. Now I get a weird behavior with the text almost no visible. Only happens on iOS.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What device is this?  Which version of iOS?

Comment: Hi, Steve. It's an iPad Mini iOS 9.2.

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble reproducing this issue.  Can you provide some sample code (preferably minimal) that will reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'll be out for a business travel all week, so I don't think I'll have the time to do this now. If you can't reproduce the issue then it's something specifical to my app, so it's gonna take some time to narrow it down. I'll get back to this as soon as I came back.

Comment: We'd appreciate something sooner as we are entering code freeze for 3.3 this week and the issue might get stuck for quite a while...

Comment: Ok, I'll try something tomorrow morning before leaving then. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed now in git.
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/74386440a2966b9d588f305c228cd7081464c9ec

Should appear on the server shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. It's been easy actually: just a visual Hello World project with a Picker in a BoxLayout Y layout. I have added it to GitHub:

https://github.com/carlosverdier/Testing

with this result on my device:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47281022/Testing%20Recording.mp4